# Command to run maven spotbug goal

Tags: maven, spotbugs

I have a maven project with `spotbugs` plugin enabled. Before committing the code, i just need to run the maven `spotbugs` check. How do i run just the spot bug check on my project?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

```
mvn spotbugs:check
```